# Updating to a Certain Clickhouse Version

Tags: clickhouse

I have two environments with two different Clickhouse versions. I want to update the lesser one to the other one's version.

When i try to install clickhouse with the version number like this:

```
sudo yum install clickhouse-server=21.10.5.3 clickhouse-client=21.10.5.3 clickhouse-common-static=21.10.5.3
```

I get an error that no package available with this version.

```
No package clickhouse-server=21.10.5.3 available.
No package clickhouse-client=21.10.5.3 available.
No package clickhouse-common-static=21.10.5.3 available.
```

As i see it the package is no longer available on their repository, when i checked the available ones i saw that there are very few versions available for installation.

Is there a way to get that specific version somehow, from another source maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add repo to yum config first, try this

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo rpm --import https://repo.clickhouse.tech/CLICKHOUSE-KEY.GPG
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://repo.clickhouse.tech/rpm/stable/x86_64
sudo yum install clickhouse-server=21.10.5.3 clickhouse-client=21.10.5.3 clickhouse-common-static=21.10.5.3
```

Comment: Hello, nothing changed sadly. Still getting  no package error

Comment: where are you installing clickhouse ? linux,windows,docker or ec2 amazon linux